# Callbacks not running when running debugger;

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-debugger

**Edit**: This question was originally about a database issue, but it turns out to be nothing of the sort. @tymeJV was quite helpful in diagnosing the problem on Friday, but on Monday morning it's very obvious the cause has nothing to do with databases.

I'm updating the question (rather than deleting it) and adding the answer myself.

There was probably some kind of problem to start with, but in the end **it was my debugging itself that was breaking things**. My code was:

```
collections.somecollection.find({name:'somename'}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  log('>>>', err,docs)          
})

debugger;
```

And I was wondering why the callback never fired.

Comment: Mind showing where `someCollection` gets defined? Also, any errors?

Comment: @tymeJV Added function used to create (all of the) collections to the question. No errs during collection creation either.

Comment: If you login through the mongo console, can you query the collection then?

Comment: @tymeJV Yep, console .find() returns all the documents.

Comment: I take it theres a `db.open(function(err, someCollection) {` somewhere?

Comment: @tymeJV I'm using MongoClient.connect() as the official docs seems to indicate that's the best thing - have added code to post. MongoClient.connect() should work though -  it just uses a URL format.

Comment: Have you tried `db.collection("someCollection").find().toArray(...`?

Comment: @tymeJV db.collection("someCollection").find().toArray(function(err, docs) { log('Returned', err, docs) } ) also fails. PS. Thanks for helping on this, I appreciate it.

Comment: Damn...hmm...after your MongoClient connects, can you see the active connection in your Mongo console? (I'm assuming the DB is running locally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the investigation itself: the debugger was pausing execution before the child scope could run its callbacks.

Eg:

```
collections.somecollection.find({name:'somename'}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  log('>>>', err,docs)          
  debugger;
})
```

Shows the callback running.

Some bugs become obvious after a little rest. Hope that helps anyone else who's in a similar position.